# Bivariate sampling for distribution expressed in Sklar's copula theorem?

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling

In the univariate case, one can easily sample a distribution via random numbers $u\sim[0,1]$ and plugging into $F^{-1}(u)$.

I have a bivariate distribution constructed via Sklar's theorem on Copulas:

$$F(x,y)=C(F(x),F(y))$$

The distribution is not in closed form.

**How do I sample from this bivariate distribution $F(x,y)$?**

Comment: Can you give the actual copula and distributions?

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 The Copula would be e.g. Normal Tempered Stable Copula, and Student t marginals. I have the MATLAB functions to calculate them, but I dont know the method for to sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniformly sample from the copula's domain $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ using acceptance-rejection method. Then use the inverse t-distribution on the resulting points to get a point in $F(x,y)$. That's the basics of how copulas work.